# jQuery dependency on a custom theme is not adding jQuery?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I know that this question has been asked previously many times but any of the solutions are not working in my case so please, I request if anyone can help me with this situation please provide me assistance.
I have added dependency of the core jQuery(along with other core libraries) in my **theme.libraries.yml** but only core jQuery is not loading in my drupal frontend and the console is showing the error of jQuery is not defined.
Also other drupal core libraries as working fine only jQuery is not loading.

My code of various files is as follows

***theme.libraries.yml***

```
global-styling:   
  version: 1.x   
  css:
    theme:
      css/bootstrap.css: {}
      css/custom.css: {}
      css/owl.carousel.min.css: {}
      css/owl.theme.default.min.css: {}
      css/responsive.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
      fonts/fonts.css: {}   
  js:
    js/bootstrap.js: {}
    js/owl.carousel.min.js: {}
    js/popper.js: {}
    js/scripts.js: {}   
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
```

**theme.info.yml**

```
name: wcsb
type: theme
description: 'Another outstanding WebCube Theme'
package: Core
version: '0.1.2'
core: '8.x'
base theme: classy

libraries:
  - wcsb/global-styling

regions:
  header_bar_1: 'Header Bar 1'
  header_bar_2: 'Header Bar 2'
  header_bar_3: 'Header Bar 3'
  header_bar_4: 'Header Bar 4'
  mobile_header_1: 'Mobile Header 1'
  mobile_header_2: 'Mobile Header 2'
  slider_images: 'Slider Images'
  breadcrumb: Breadcrumb
  featured_top: 'Featured top'
  above_content: 'Above Content'
  content: Content
  below_content: 'Below Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
  sidebar_second: 'Sidebar second'
  featured_bottom_first: 'Featured bottom first'
  featured_bottom_second: 'Featured bottom second'
  featured_bottom_third: 'Featured bottom third'
  footer_first: 'Footer first'
  footer_second: 'Footer second'
  footer_third: 'Footer third'
  footer_fourth: 'Footer fourth'
  footer_fifth: 'Footer fifth'
```

**list of scripts loading**

```
<body class="path-frontpage page-node-type-page" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1002.0" data-gr-ext-installed=""
cz-shortcut-listen="true">

<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">
    {
        "path": {
            "baseUrl": "\/",
            "scriptPath": null,
            "pathPrefix": "",
            "currentPath": "node\/1",
            "currentPathIsAdmin": false,
            "isFront": true,
            "currentLanguage": "en"
        },
        "pluralDelimiter": "\u0003",
        "suppressDeprecationErrors": true,
        "ajaxTrustedUrl": {
            "form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM": true
        },
        "user": {
            "uid": 0,
            "permissionsHash": "508c848d9cf616f3b3735479b8cad945e128b7dbb0a534206170c7d3643afe05"
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery-once/jquery.once.min.js?v=2.2.3"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/wcsb/js/bootstrap.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/wcsb/js/owl.carousel.min.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/wcsb/js/popper.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/themes/custom/wcsb/js/scripts.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/cart/js/commerce_cart.js?v=8.9.13"></script>
```

**console errors**
[image: console showing jquery is not defined errors.]

Comment: Can you try with the `version: 1.x` removed?

Comment: @leymannx I removed `version: 1.x` but nothing changed, issue is still there

Comment: You flushed caches at least twice of course?

Comment: @leymannx yes I have cleared cache about dozen of times but noting happend

Comment: Did you check if the file actually exists in `core/assets/vendor/jquery-once/jquery.once.min.js` in the location just to be sure. And Also disable css and js aggregation.

Comment: @miststudent2011 file already exists in the directory mentioned by you and CSS and js aggregation is disabled also. jQuery is not added only in my theme in other custom themes jquery is working perfectly.

Comment: Since everything you have shown us seems OK, the natural conclusion is the issue is elsewhere. Could you try adding the bare essentials of your custom theme - no PHP, just the files required by info and library, to a fresh Drupal install, and enabling it there?

Comment: Thanks @AlfredArmstrong for providing your suggestion to review the PHP files as problem was in my .theme file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** The problem was in my .theme file where it was unsetting the core jQuery library.
The problem code:

```
function theme_js_alter(&$javascript, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets)
{
    unset($javascript['core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js']);
}
```

Thanks to **@AlfredArmstrong** for providing the suggestion of reviewing the php files